# Get the value from the checked radio button and add to cart in PHP

Tags: php

I am building a website for order food online. I am trying to get the value from the radio button if checked. When I checked either radio button, and add to cart, it always give me only one value. So, how can I get the value if the radio button checked? Any help would be great! Thank you.

Here is my code.

**DB** (table name is `items`)

```
id | product_code | product_name       | product_desc       | product_img_name | price | price2 | product_type
1  | AS01         | Dumpling           | Two for Each Order | 1.png            | 2.50  | NULL   | appitezer_soup
2  | HS02         | Chicken Fried Rice | ''                 | 2.png            | 5.50  | 7.50   | house_specials
```

Chicken Fried Rice has two size `Regular ($5.50)` and `Large ($7.50)`. And here I want to add to cart if the radio button is checked.

**index.php**

```
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE product_type='house_specials' ORDER BY id ASC");
        if ($results) { 

        //fetch results set as object and output HTML
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
          echo '<div class="product">'; 
          echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
          // echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"></div>';
          echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
          echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
          echo '<div class="product-info">';
          echo '<label for="pt">PT '.$currency.$obj->price.'</label><input id="pt" type="radio" name="productSize" value="PT"/>';
          echo '<label for="qt">QT '.$currency.$obj->price2.'</label><input id="qt" class="size_butt" type="radio" name="productSize" value="QT"/>';
          // echo 'Price: '.$currency.$obj->price.' | ';
          echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />';
          echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
          echo '</div></div>';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
          echo '</form>';
          echo '</div>';
        }

    } 
h2>Your Cart</h2>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["items"]))
{
    $total = 0;
    echo '<ol>';
    if (isset($_SESSION["items"])) {

    foreach ($_SESSION["items"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
        echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
        echo '<h3>'.$cart_itm["name"].'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="p-code">P code : '.$cart_itm["code"].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="p-price">Price :'.$currency.$cart_itm["price"].'</div>';
        echo '</li>';
        $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    echo '<span class="check-out-txt"><strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong> <a href="view_cart.php"><button>Check-out!</button></a></span>';
    echo '<span class="empty-cart"><a href="cart_update.php?emptycart=1&return_url='.$current_url.'"><button>Empty Cart</button></a></span>';
  }
} else {
   echo 'Your cart is empty';
}
```

**cart_update**

```
if(isset($_POST["type"]) || $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $product_qty    = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url

    //MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name, price, price2 FROM items WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
    $obj = $results->fetch_object();

    if ($results) { //we have the product info 

        //prepare array for the session variable
        $new_product = array(array('name'=>$obj->product_name, 'code'=>$product_code, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$obj->price, 'price2'=>$obj->price2));

        if(isset($_SESSION["items"])) //if we have the session
        {
            $found = false; //set found item to false

            foreach ($_SESSION["items"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
            {
                if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code){ //the item exist in array

                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"], 'price2'=>$cart_itm["price2"]);
                    $found = true;
                }else{
                    //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrive old info and prepare array for session var
                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"], 'price2'=>$cart_itm["price2"]);
                }
            }

            if($found == false) //we didn't find item in array
            {
                //add new user item in array
                $_SESSION["items"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
            }else{
                //found user item in array list, and increased the quantity
                $_SESSION["items"] = $product;
            }

        }else{
            //create a new session var if does not exist
            $_SESSION["items"] = $new_product;
        }

    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder :  `if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')` you're checking if a var is defined and if its value equals to something in the same condition. This is not a good practice since it's gonna throw an error if it's undefined.

Comment: you can get radio input value same like other inputs using post e.g 

$productSize    = $_POST["productSize"]; in update_cart.php

Comment: @AamirSarwar Can you please specific where can I add in the update_cart? Thanks

Comment: See it in my answer below. Also filter the value

Comment: just a reminder: `if (isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"] == 'add') { ..` is safe! Why? :  `&&` will not continue if the first test fails. In all cases, to continue it must have a value to be compared against. (see 'short circuit evaluation')

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt What do you mean? "You check if it's defined ... will throw an error if undefined" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it

```
 $productSize = $_POST["productSize"];
```

under these lines in update_cart page

```
    $product_code   = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $product_qty    = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
    $productSize    = $_POST["productSize"]; // value of radio button
```

---

change below lines in index file

```
echo '<label for="pt">PT '.$currency.$obj->price.'</label><input id="pt" type="radio" name="productSize" value="PT"/>';
echo '<label for="qt">QT '.$currency.$obj->price2.'</label><input id="qt" class="size_butt" type="radio" name="productSize" value="QT"/>';
```

to

```
echo '<label for="pt">PT '.$currency.$obj->price.'</label><input id="pt" type="radio" name="productSize" value="'.$obj->price.'"/>';
echo '<label for="qt">QT '.$currency.$obj->price2.'</label><input id="qt" class="size_butt" type="radio" name="productSize" value="'.$obj->price2.'"/>';
```

and change below line in update cart page

```
$new_product = array(array('name'=>$obj->product_name, 'code'=>$product_code, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$obj->price, 'price2'=>$obj->price2));
```

to

```
$new_product = array(array('name'=>$obj->product_name, 'code'=>$product_code, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$_POST["productSize"], 'price2'=>$obj->price2));
```

Hope this will resolve issue

Comment: Thank you. I added that line like you said, but I still couldn't get the radio button value. Any idea?

Comment: you will only get the value of radio button if any one (radio button) is selected. Other wise form will not post value of non selected radio button. Are you sure you selected the radio button?

Comment: Yes, I checked one of the two price option, still only give the first price in the cart

Comment: if  radio buttons have same name then you will only get one value (that is selected). Do you also get the first value if you select second radio button?

Comment: Yes, either one I selected, I always get the first value. I've updated the code to display the item in the cart in the **index.php**. I've been trying to check if the radio button is selected there. I am not sure if I am on the right track. Please take a look and give me some advise. Thank you

Comment: I saw your update, and yes, the problem is solved. Now I can get the value from selected radio button. However, for the item that only has one price, when I add to cart, it doesn't show the price in the cart. I've updated the code to display the item's detail in the cart in the **index.php**. I think I have to change something in that code, could you please take a look and give me some advise? Thanks